# Possible to add end points using REST UI module?

Tags: 9

I'm using the REST UI module with Drupal 9 with a view. Right now I have my default path which is /api/directory, and this has the fields I want in the API, for example title.

Is it possible to create an endpoint such as /api/directory?title=""

So that way instead of loading all the data on my site, I can only load what is necessary?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can create custom REST endpoints, but not with the REST UI module; you [need to write your own code and put it in a custom module](https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/restful-web-services-api/custom-rest-resources).